# Visual code - no option to select g++ for debug - C++

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, g++, vscode-debugger

ive encountered an issue where on some programs there is no option to select g++ when I choose to run and debug. I know I've set g++ up correctly as if I create a simple hello world program, i can run via g++.

But for some reason on more complex programs I cannot, and automatically get assigned GDB as the debug setting. I'm a novice programmer so im not sure what the issue is. Is there something specific in actual code that can prevent g++ from being used? I've messed around with settings and any workaround always ends up with an error message for a lack of a .exe at the assigned path.

thanks for any help

Comment: Your launch.json and tasks.json determine this if you are not using a different extension.

Comment: To create and run a program in C++ you have to do it in four steps: 1) Edit the source code; 2) Build the source code into object files; 3) Link object files into an executable file; And 4) Run the executable file. For simple project (one or two source files) step 2 and 3 could be combined into a single step. The compiler front-end program `g++` is involved only in step 2 and 3. To debug a program you take an already existing executable file, and run it *inside* a debugger (like for example GDB).

Comment: The problem could be in the "preLaunchTask" of launch.json: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp) it should match the label of the build task of tasks.json